# jQuery validation, Date Format mm/yyyy validates on keyup

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to validate my input fields before processing it to payment using Stripe.

For card number I created an input box:

```
<input type="text" class="credit-card" id="cardnumber" name="cardnumber" size="30" value="" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX">
```

I validate it in a manner that after every 4 digits it put `-` automatically:

```
String.prototype.toCardFormat = function () {
     return this.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").substr(0, 16).split("").reduce(cardFormat, "");
function cardFormat(str, l, i) {
    return str + ((!i || (i % 4)) ? "" : "-") + l;
   }
};
$(".credit-card").keyup(function () {
      $(this).val($(this).val().toCardFormat());
});
```

Now I need to validate the date as the user start entering `mm`, it automatically adds `/` and make it in format `mm/yyyy` . So that this should be valid date:

```
05/2016
```

but not these:

```
13/2018
05/2006
5/19
05/19
06-2019
05 2019
```

Also I used replace method to restrict user to enter ant text and symbols.

Comment: It might be easier for the date to have a date picker using a library or using two textboxes separated by a slash.

Comment: @depperm I appreciate your comment but I am trying to do something diffrent. :)

Comment: From your post it looks like you want the user to enter a valid date. Using the datepicker jquery lib you can set a min date and date format. Why don't you use a premade lib?

Comment: @depperm i need only textboxes and labels in my website.datepicker may not match our form. If I failed to do so,I will use prelibs, but if I put year as 4567, they will accept, I will restrict them to enter 2015 to 2040

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API to validate credit card inputs. 
http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/
or check out this blog on validation for Stripe API.
https://stripe.com/blog/jquery-payment

Answer (score 1):

Use a plugin Jquery validate that the best one for validation fields.
Check this link below :
http://jqueryvalidation.org/creditcard-method/

Answer (score 1):

onkeyup i called the function called mdate>>

```
function mdata(v){
    v=v.replace(/\D/g,""); //Remove what is not a digit
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");       
    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");       

    v=v.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,"$1$2");
    return v;
}
```

it will display 29/04/2000 and will auto put the "/".

i put this inside the html and it worked for me.